# Spring Boot - Request with object with MultpartFile

Tags: java, spring-boot

I indend to create a request that receive a lot of data of one driver with MultpartFiles and others data:

```
public class Driver {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private MultipartFile image;
    private MultipartFile document;
    private Car[] cars;
}

public class Car {
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private MultipartFile image;
    private MultipartFile document;
}
```

So, I trid to use

```
public ResponseEntity<?> createDriver(@ModelAttribute Driver driver)
```

However it's not working.

How can I make a request saving a object with MultpartFile in JavaSpringboot? Is it possible?